# How to pass a vector element of type string as argument to pthread_create()?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am trying to pass string type vector element to the pthread_create() function.  The message is not getting printed in the output. Where am I wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *print_thread_details(void  *thread_no){

    std::string str = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(thread_no);
    cout<<"\n Running thread = "<<str<<endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main(){

/*initialize an array of pthreads*/

    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;

    vector<string> v(NUM_THREADS);
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
        string s = "Thread No = ";
        char temp = i+'0';
        s=s+temp;
        v.push_back(s);

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_thread_details,&v[i] );

        if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
    }

 pthread_exit(NULL);
return 0;

}
```

Output:

Running thread =

Running thread =

Running thread =

Running thread =

Running thread =

Comment: If you have access to C++11 I really suggest you give `std::thread` a shot.  It actually works with the type system which means no more `void*`'s.

Comment: Why are you writing C-style code in C++? Why are you using macros for constants? Why are you not using `std::thread`?

Answer (score 1):

> How to pass a vector element of type string as argument to pthread_create()?

Exactly how you pass them now.

However, you must take care to prevent the strings from being destroyed or moved while the thread is alive.

> The message is not getting printed in the output.

All of the strings that you pass to the threads are empty.

---

I suspect that you are confused about how vectors work:

> ```
> vector<string> v(NUM_THREADS);
> ```

This constructs a vector of 5 elements. Each of the 5 string are empty.

> ```
> v.push_back(s);
> ```

This adds a 6th ... 10th element into the vector. These strings are not empty, but also aren't passed to the threads because you used the indices 0...4, which contain the empty strings.

Furthermore, these push backs may cause the vector to reallocate, in which case the pointers passed to the threads created earlier would become invalid, resulting in undefined behaviour.

You should probably replace this with:

```
 v[i] = s;
```

Another approach is to start with an empty vector, and push the generated strings in the loop. But in that case you must pre-reserve the memory to avoid pointer invalidation due to reallocation. Or fill the vector in a separate loop, before starting any threads.

---

PS. `print_thread_details` returns `void*` but is missing a return statement. The behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the vector constructor that pre-fills the vector with blank strings, and then afterwards you are pushing additional non-blank strings onto the end of the vector.  The vector will end up with 10 strings, not 5.  But the threads will only see the blank strings.

Remove the value you are passing to the vector constructor, then the vector will be empty initially.  Call the vector's `reserve()` method instead to preallocate the vector without actually adding items to it:

```
vector<string> v;
v.reserve(NUM_THREADS);
```

Otherwise, without the `reserve()`, each call to `push_back()` will potentially reallocate the vector's internal area, invalidating any existing string pointers, which would be bad when you populate the vector and create the threads at the same time.  The safer approach is to push all of the strings into the vector before then creating the threads:

```
vector<string> v;

for(int i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
    // consider using std::ostringstream instead...
    string s = "Thread No = ";
    char temp = i+'0';
    s=s+temp;
    v.push_back(s);
}

for(int i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print_thread_details,&v[i] );
    ...
}
```

On a side note, once you start the threads, you need to wait for them to terminate before allowing `main()` to exit, otherwise the vector can be destroyed while the threads are still using the string values.